# How do I rename a parameter with Tuckey urlrewrite?

Tags: java, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm using the Tuckey urlrewrite filter with `use-query-string` set to the default (false). This means that the from urls don't use the query parameters to match. What I'd like to do in an isolated case is rename one query parameter, which would require matching the query-string in the from tag.

For example, I would like to do this:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/myPage?id=(.*)$</from>
    <to>/newPage?userId=$1</to>
</rule>
```

This is possible with `use-query-string=true`, unfortunately that would be a global change and there are many rules which would break if I change this setting.

Is there a way to override `use-query-string` for a single rule?

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 2):

I found a hint to the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995673/urlrewrite-tuckey-hide-specific-parameter-if-exists) unanswered question. You can use the 'backreferences' functionality, as described in the [manual](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html#configuration) (although its not very clear how it works)

```
<rule>
    <from>^/mypage$</from>
    <to type="redirect" >/newPage?userId=%{parameter:id}</to>
</rule>
```